# When do we exactly get Messaging exception - no data input stream data source?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have the following piece of code:

```
 Multipart mp = (Multipart)part.getContent();  
 int count = mp.getCount(); // This line throws the Messaging Exception
```

The stacktrace of the exception is below:

> 24 Feb 2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: No inputstream from datasource 24 Feb
>   2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -  at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parsebm(MimeMultipart.java:646) 24
>   Feb 2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -  at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parse(MimeMultipart.java:383) 24 Feb
>   2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -  at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.getCount(MimeMultipart.java:229) 24
>   Feb 2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -  at
>   com.xerox.docushare.mailagent.Archive.processForDocUpload(Archive.java:1825)
>   24 Feb 2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -   at
>   com.xerox.docushare.mailagent.Archive.processForUpload(Archive.java:422)
>   24 Feb 2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -   at
>   com.xerox.docushare.mailagent.Archive.doArchive(Archive.java:90) 24
>   Feb 2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -  at
>   com.xerox.docushare.mailagent.ProcessMgr.onProcess(ProcessMgr.java:122)
>   24 Feb 2016 05:19:52 - [Thread[Thread-67,5,main]] -   at
>   com.xerox.docushare.mailagent.ProcessMgr.run(ProcessMgr.java:324)

After some search, I got that it was probably cause of due to a lost connection to the server. So i added code to reconnect in the catch block of this exception ! However, I still get the same exception. So probably connection was never a problem !!

Has anyone come across this problem (I am sure many have) and found the exact cause and solution ? Please HELP !

Comment: Are you sure you are getting exception when calling 'getCount'? The exception should be from first line.

Comment: Yes. Definite ! Checked taht already with debug logs. Always for the second line !

Comment: Your mail server may be returning an incorrect response that JavaMail can't parse.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  Are you using POP3 or IMAP?  What version of JavaMail are you using?